# Are there any conventions about what size could call big or small in data structures?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have a problem understanding that in Java, DOM parser is good for small XML files/streams, but not a good option for big ones.

Can it be specified the definition of a small or big XML? Does it depends on how many KB or MB the file is, or the structure counts too?

Of course, I can check it by implementing it, and testing the performance, but I guess it takes too much time this way.

Comment: "big" = "big enough that you notice the memory usage". "small" = "smaller than that"

Comment: No, it does not take "too much time" to generate an XML file containing a structure according to your implementation and unmarshalling that. Tying to guess based on reports from others that *may* have written good programs for *some* XML structure on this or that system with this or that file system and this or that hardware: Would you really proceed on that?

Comment: I meant the "too much time" for implementing it by using DOM, making test XMLs in the possible ranges, run test cases, and if I found it slow, implement it again using SAX, run tests again is much more time than picking the proper one first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to ask the question. Real engineers don't talk about "big" and "small", they use numbers. You don't ask whether it would be very expensive to bridge a very wide river, you ask how much it would cost to bridge a 1Km-wide river.

Very often with memory, there's a discontinuity between things that fit in main memory and things that don't. So if available memory is 2Gb, then things above 2Gb might require a different design approach from things below 2Gb. So a statement that a particular design (e.g. DOM) is good for "small" documents but not for "big" ones might be understood in terms of this discontinuity.

Incidentally, the term "DOM" is sometimes used specifically for the W3C DOM, and sometimes as a generic term for in-memory tree representations. DOM itself, in the sence of org.w3.dom, is NEVER the best technical approach; third-party tree models such as JDOM2 and XOM are ALWAYS better. People only use DOM out of ignorance of the alternatives, or because they believe it has merit because it is "standard".

Answer (score 2):

It's not inherently good or bad. It's just that it loads all the nodes of the document, with their content, in memory, and SAX allows avoiding that.

Of course, if your document is 100 MBs large and has a unique root element with a huge text that you need to have in memory, using SAX instead of DOM probably won't change much in terms of memory consumption.

But if you have millions of elements and want to process each element one by one, using SAX allows keeping the memory usage very low, whereas DOM doesn't.

Comment: I rather than looking for a range (if exist) to define my XMLs as big or small. For example a table in databases with a few thousand records still count as a small one (of course it depends on the size of the records too, but for this example in that table there aren't `longtext` and other huge data elements)

Comment: There is no range. My biggest database ever is probably tiny in the context of Google. And an Android application running on an old phone doesn't have the same constraints as a server application running on a 16-core machine with 128 GB of RAM. Measure, and if it's fast enough and doesn't blow up your available memory, then it's OK

Comment: Ah, I see the point I guess. So "small" and "big" mostly depends on your system.